# MouseClick events on transparent Forms without interrupting events on background apps

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to check when and where user uses mouse while using his computer. For that, I created transparent Form which stays always in foreground. The problem is, it doesn't behave as I expected it to.

For some reason, when I choose `backgroundColor` and `transparencyKey` of Form to `Red` I can read MouseEvents but I can't do anything on apps that stays in background. I can see through Form as it's transparent, but I can't make any actions using mouse on apps that stays behind it.

On the other hand, when I set `backgroundColor` and `transparencyKey` to `Control` (System color) I can operate on other apps, but MouseEvents doesn't work.

Is there any simple way I could use MouseEvents and be able to use other windows apps at the same time?

Comment: Definitely it's not a good approach. Why don't you think about create a service instead of a form, asking for the O.S. API to be notified on every mouse click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need control Mouse or Keyboard activity at system level there is only one way, but is not simple: Use hooks. See [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) for reference.

SetWindowsHookEx is a Windows API that intercepts all the keyboard and/or mouse activity and allows to your application retrieve the information.

[Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-mouse-hook-in-c/) and [here (version 1)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) there are a couple of examples.